# Dismissing imagePickerController while holding the device landscape style causes my app to rotate into landscape mode (but my app is portrait only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a portrait and portrait upside-down app.  I present an imagePickerController and it allows me to take pictures which can be either landscape or portrait.  after taking a picture, the imagePicker verifies if I want to use the photo that was taken.  If I hold my device 'sideways' (in a landscape fashion), the image picker view will dismiss like normal and my original view controller will be displayed, except it is in landscape mode (including the keyboard).  This should be impossible because my app only supports portrait orientations.

Any ideas on how to keep my app in portrait mode so that the UI doesn't get messed up?

This is my app before I open the imagePicker:
[image: This is my app before I open the imagePicker]

This is the imagePicker right before I dismiss it.  although this screenshot is in portrait mode, please imagine that I am holding the device SIDEWAYS (landscape style):
[image]

This is the resulting bugged out screen, that I would like to prevent:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would first check Info.plist and confirm that the orientation is correct and does not contain any landscape options for either iphone or ipad:

[image: Info.plist should look like this]

Comment: the plist only contains portrait

Comment: How about trying this code, placed just after viewdidload method in the view controller where the image picker is called: 
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}